# Picasso context cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, picasso, android-context

I am trying to download images from URL to and SD card. To perform this task I added the Picasso library in my app and tried this code to download images to the SD card:

```
package com.example.imagedownloadsample;

import java.io.File;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.squareup.picasso.Target;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image_download);

        Button bn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // do something to download images to sd card

                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        "Android/data/com.usd.pop");
                file.mkdirs();
                Picasso.with(context).load("your URL").into(file);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

but I got this error:

> Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
>       context cannot be resolved to a variable    MainActivity.java   /ImageDownloadSample/src/com/example/imagedownloadsample    line 31 Java Problem

Comment: That is because you don't have a `context` variable anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try to replace this code,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Context context;
    private Button bn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image_download);
        context = this;
        bn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do something to download images to sd card

                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        "Android/data/com.usd.pop");
                file.mkdirs();
                Picasso.with(context).load("your URL").into(file);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic way :

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("your URL").into(file);
```